# What does it mean an object starts with an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, object, error-handling

Sometimes I got an error like this which fired from `catch(err => console.log(err))`:

```
{ [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: table_name] errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' }
```

It looks like an object and yeah it is, but why is there an array in the beginning of it?

How can I get that array?

I want to get that error message:

```
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: table_name
```

To decide what to do next.

I thought the error message was part of the key name so I tried:

```
Object.keys(err);
```

But return an array like this:

```
["errno", "code"]
```

How to get that error message?

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone What is the "something" that will get the error message he wants?

Comment: try `console.log(err.message)`

Comment: After re-reading, asker is mistaking the `[Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: table_name]` output when `err` is converted to a string to be an erray. I think Ilya Bursov has the answer.

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone He specifically said he wants the message `Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: table_name`. But that doesn't seem to be one of the properties.

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone The error object apparently has a `toString()` method that produces the string he got, with the array around the message at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*IIRC....* `sqlite` uses the built in `Error` object. What you see in brackets is **not** an array; it is actually a human-readable error description string which is in brackets (perhaps for emphasis).

```js
try {
   ....
} catch (err) {
   console.log(err.message); // this should be your error message.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is throwing the error is not throwing a simple string. Try a different logging method to get a better idea of what is being returned, as `console.log` may not be giving you the correct value of the error when being logged.

Try using `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error)))` and see what is returned. It may be that you need to do something like `console.log(error.response.message)` or something similar to get a more useful string you can use.

`console.log` may also be running a custom `toString` method on the returned object, like this, for example: https://repl.it/@Twinbird24/WingedCloudyTrials